# Change range of values with html slider

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array of values from 0-100 i.e [20, 22, 30, 40]. I'd like to be able to change all the values uniformly with an HTML slider + some JS.

```
var ogarray = [20, 22, 30, 40];

var newarray = // [80, 82, 90, 100]
```

With a min of 0 and a max of 100 if done correctly the new array values would be [80, 82, 90, 100]

Comment: Hi, do you have any code that you can show?

Comment: no one knows what you mean...

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you want the slider to be an OFFSET with minimum and maximum values being dependent on the min and max values in the array?

Comment: @AndrewFan you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I could get from your answer and Andrew Fan's comment

```js
let oldArray = [20, 22, 30, 40];
let newArray;
let output = document.getElementById("output")
output.innerText = `Move the slider`
let slider = document.getElementById("slider")
slider.min = oldArray[0]
slider.max = oldArray[oldArray.length-1]
slider.addEventListener("change", () => {
    newArray = [];
    oldArray.sort()
    oldArray.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (item + Number(slider.value) <= 100) {
            newArray.push(item + Number(slider.value))
        }
        else {
            newArray.push(100)
        }
        output.innerText = `newArray: ${newArray}`
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 id="output"></h1>
        <input id="slider" type="range" value=0></input>
    </body>
</html>
```

It sets the min and max of the slider to the least and greatest elements in `oldArray`. When the slider changes it sets each element in `newArray` to the `oldArray` element plus the slider's position.

It does not change anything about the slider's min or max. It adds the exact slider's position. Meaning when the slider is at the left side it adds 20 or whatever the least value is in oldArray.

[Here is a link to input ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to add 60 to all numbers in the array. If this `60` comes from the slider, then just use it.

```js
var ogarray = [20, 22, 30, 40];
const add = 60;
const res = ogarray.map(e => e + add);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 separate sliders. One makes sure the slider doesnt go below min or above max, and one that stops the array values going below min or above max.

```js
var values = [20,22,30,40];
        var min = 0;
        var max = 100;
        function slide1(slide) {
            tempValues = [...values];
            for(x=0; x<tempValues.length; x++) {
                tempValues[x] += Number(slide.value);
            }
            console.log(tempValues);
        }

        function slide2(slide) {
            highest = Math.max(...values);
            lowest = Math.min(...values);
            slideValue = Number(slide.value);
            if(highest + slideValue <= max || slideValue - lowest >= min) {
                slide.min = min - lowest - slideValue;
                slide.max = max - highest - slideValue;
                slide.value = (slide.max - slide.min) / 2;
                for(x=0; x<values.length; x++) {
                    values[x] += slideValue;
                }
            }
            console.log(values);
        }

        window.onload = init;
        
        function init() {
            slide = document.getElementById('myRange2');
            highest = Math.max(...values);
            lowest = Math.min(...values);
            slide.max = max - highest;
            slide.min = min - lowest;
        }
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
        <label>slide 1</label>
            <input onchange="slide1(this)" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
            <label>slide 2</label>
            <input onchange="slide2(this)" type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange2">
        </div>
```